# Why concatenation does not work in Dbeaver?

Tags: sql, mariadb, dbeaver

Using Dbeaver, the `||` concatenation does not work. Had to use `CONCAT()` instead.
Got output error message: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value. Anyone else had this issue?

Skill level: Beginner 
Editor: Dbeaver 
OS: Windows 7

Comment: Depending upon the `sql_mode` settings, the `||` to be used for concat-ing might not be enabled. What do you get from `SELECT @@sql_mode;` ?

Comment: After inputting `SELECT @@sql_mode` I get the following: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`   I've searched what this means but still don't understand, unfortunately. Also tried `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` and `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` but got the same results.

Comment: Yep, I don't see `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`, so you can add that by doing: `SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',PIPES_AS_CONCAT'));`. That information [found here](https://database.guide/7-options-for-enabling-pipes-as-the-concatenation-operator-in-mariadb/).

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help and the link to the article @Paul T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB expects the `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` to be set with the `sql_mode` to use `||` as a concat operator.

One can check what is set for `sql_mode` by doing:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

To which output similar to the following may appear:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Note that the `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` is not listed, so this can be appended by doing:

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT'));
```

Then recheck the `sql_mode` to see:

```
root@localhost((none))select @@sql_mode \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
@@sql_mode: PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,
            NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
            NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

More information about `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` can be [found here](https://database.guide/7-options-for-enabling-pipes-as-the-concatenation-operator-in-mariadb/).